# cocos2dx - get transition progress after CCDirector::pushScene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am writing my own CCLayer by extending CCLayer in cocos2d-x-2.1.4. I used `CCDirector::pushScene()` method to push the scene that contains my CCLayer.. when I push a `CCTransitionSlide***` scene, my `CCCustomLayer::visit()` will get call continuously. How do I get the transition progress within that method? I'll need to know the progress for animating my custom layer...

I am new to cocos2d-x- and have no idea at all. I've investigated the variables that changed throughout the call but they doesn't seem to tally with what I'm looking out.. Thanks!

Comment: some code might help for better understanding on what you exactly want :)